# Why isn't the multisession login in Lion's VNC server working properly?

Tags: mac, macos, remote-desktop

Has anyone been able to get the VNC server that came with Lion to work? Right now it seems to have problems with the new multisession remote login, causing problems for any VNC clients connecting to the server (see below). Is there a workaround for this problem, other than installing another VNC server on the system?

Further details:

When connection over VNC, you're presented with a login screen (this is the new multisession feature mentioned above). The problem is that the screen usually doesn't let you even click on one of the users' icons, and the times you can get that far, it doesn't let you enter a password.

Comment: You could also use Vine Server for Lion-like screen sharing. Read more about it [here](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/lion-like-screen-sharing-without-lion.html)

Answer (score 2):

Wow - I was unprepared for the change where I don't just see whatever was on the screen and instead are presented with a second loginwindow instance.

My brain reels at the implications for Mac OS X Lion client acting like windows terminal server with multiple independent log in sessions. I bet a lot of software will break assuming it's the only copy running on the mac.

As to your question - I can't get VNC to break - either using Screen Sharing on another mac or using [Screens app on iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-client-for-ios/id400012962?mt=8). It works like a champ for me, and I didn't change anything from a previously working Snow Leopard system. The upgrade left all my settings and VNC passwords alone and operational.

Answer (score 2):

> …  get the VNC server that came with Lion to work? Right now it seems to have problems with the new multisession remote login, causing problems for any VNC clients …

Where a service issue is suspected, try the following in the Sharing pane of System Preferences:

1. enable remote management (overrides screen sharing)
2. restart the operating system
3. disable remote management then enable screen sharing
4. restart the operating system.

After each one of the steps, see whether the VNC client (where difficulty is noted) works reliably.