# RealVNC on Lion

Tags: mac, macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I've been using [RealVNC Server](http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/index.html) on my Mac for years, since it gives me encryption and other features used by RealVNC's clients for iOS and Windows. Once I upgraded to Lion, though, it broke. Now, I see a completely black screen while connected. The cursor moves around fine (which I can see while seated at the monitor, and used as an ad-hoc mouse when Lion initially didn't pair with my Magic Trackpad), but no image comes through.

I only discovered the [problem with the built-in VNC server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16905/8174) when I tried falling back on it to temporarily replace RealVNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately seems that Apple has permormed sufficient changes in Apple MAC OS X LION to give it incompatible with the actual Releases of REAL VNC. Contacted them, they told me that they are on the way to build a new release LION compatible. Expect to have the new release as a normal update at no extra cost, as I have renewed my support to them ine week ago. Regards ;)

Comment: If you find a link to relevant information published by RealVNC, please add a comment (or edit your answer). Thanks!

Comment: Version 4.6.2 brought Lion compatibility. @GrahamPerrin: the release notes here detail the Lion changes in 4.6.2 and 4.6.3: http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/4.6/release-notes.html