# How to boot 2015 Mac Pro without monitor

Tags: display, macos, startup, mac-pro

I have a mac pro which I and several colleagues access through screen sharing.  It has no need of an external monitor itself.  Periodically, it shuts down (perhaps because of university-mandated update) and won't restart without a monitor attached.  How can I get it to reboot without a monitor?

Comment: Not sure why it's "required" but here's an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233861/119271) to a similar question re: a Mac mini and remote management (aka screen sharing) that may solve your issue.

Comment: You can also see why it shut down by going through the system log and finding the "shutdown cause" entries.