# Remote Desktop Connection from Windows to Mac

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, pc

I have a Mac Mini I use occasionally. I use RealVNC to connect to it remotely, from my Windows computer. VNC works well, but it lacks a few useful features. The two main features I'm missing is the ability to match the Mac's resolution to that of my PC screen, and the ability to transfer files between both computers.

Is there a simple way to install an RDP server on the Mac (it can be a paid solution)? Or perhaps there is another solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in VNC server on Mac OS:
System Preferences -> Sharing -> Screen Sharing
It won't transfer files from another platform than Mac.

On PC side I used [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com) in the past.

[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com) could be one solution.

All Mac solutions need the GPU and hardware to think there is a full resolution display attached, so get a 4K “Ghost display adapter” if you [want more resolution on the remote side](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/233861/5472). You can also use software to choose resolutions that are not offered by default.

- https://www.madrau.com/

Comment: I am using the built in VNC server on the Mac. I just don't know how I can set the client on the PC to use the entire screen resolution , and not the Mac's resolution.

Comment: VNC transfers the whole screen as an image. You can't have different screen resolution on the (host) Mac and client (PC) without scaling the client window.

Comment: That's what I suspected. So is there an RDP solution for the Mac?

Comment: See my edit @zmbq the OS doesn’t make up larger display sizes than it detects at boot or when a new display is detected.